# Django Testing Model Attributes

Tags: python, django

Below is an screenshot of my current coverage.py report.

[image]

I am unsure how to get **100% coverage for this model**. How do I test for **lines 13-20**? In my `tests_model.py` I assumed by creating an instance this would be covered. But this is not the case.

```
# Core Django imports
from django.test import TestCase

# Third-party app imports
import nose.tools as noz
from model_mommy import mommy
from model_mommy.recipe import Recipe, foreign_key


# app imports
from ..models.company import Company
from testapp.apps.profiles.models.appUserModel import AppUser

class CompanyModel(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.company = mommy.make(Company)
        noz.assert_true(isinstance(self.company, Company))


    def test_company_user_count_is_0(self):
        company = mommy.make(Company)
        noz.assert_equal(company.company_user_count(), 0)

    def test_company_user_count(self):
        # Relationship can be one-to-many with users.
        company = mommy.make(Company)
        user1, user2 = mommy.make(AppUser, _quantity=2)
        company.users.add(user1)
        company.users.add(user2)
        noz.assert_equal(company.company_user_count(), 2)


    def test_company_unicode(self):
        noz.assert_equal(self.company.__unicode__(), self.company.name)
```

I have tried to test each attributes own its own in the same test file, for example...

```
def test_name(self):
    company = mommy.make(Company, name="Test Name")
    noz.assert_equal(company.name, "Test Name")
```

But this has no impact whatsoever on my coverage score.

Based on comments I have also tried this:

```
def test_name(self):
    company = mommy.make(Company)
    company.name = "Test"
    company.save()
    noz.assert_equal(company.name, "Test")
```

But again, this had no impact on score.

These are my settings for tests...

```
INSTALLED_APPS += (

    'django_nose',
    'django_coverage',
    'django_extensions',

)

TEST_RUNNER = 'django_nose.NoseTestSuiteRunner'

NOSE_ARGS = [
    '--with-coverage',
    '--cover-package=testapp.apps.profiles,testapp.apps.referrals',
    '--cover-html'

]
```

Console output:

```
> python manage.py test
.........
Name                                                               Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
testapp.apps.referrals.models                                       1      1     0%   1
testapp.apps.referrals.models.company                               17     15    12%   1-24, 27
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                                                136     73    46%
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Directory:

```
testapp/
       manage.py
       testapp/
              __init__.py
              apps/
                  __init__.py
                  referrals/
                           __init__.py
                           tests/
                                __init__.py
                                model_tests.py
```

Comment: How about update your model with some dummy data?

Comment: @neo_blackcap you mean take the already created instance self.company and update each attribute? Just tried that  company.name = "Test" with no impact on score sorry :)

Comment: either create or update is OK. I just think the result should save into database, not just in the memory.

Comment: There's something odd going on with your coverage here, as simply importing the model in the test should have run those lines.

Comment: @neo_blackcap updated OP with what I tried again with no impact on score. :(

Comment: @DanielRoseman Hi Daniel, I have updated the OP with the whole test file and my setting so you can see how I am using these packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this issue](https://bitbucket.org/kmike/django-coverage/issue/19/coverage-misses-models-and-admin) on django_coverage project page.

Also, take a look to [coverage.py official FAQ](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/faq.html#faq), in particular this one:

```
Q: Why do the bodies of functions (or classes) show as executed,
   but the def lines do not?
```

Seems that the coverage machinery is started **after** your model is actually imported.

Try to back to a *standard* Django testing scenario (using a builtin test runner) and run coverage manually by issuing these commands:

```
coverage run --source='.' ./manage.py test
coverage report
coverage html
```

See if the report is different.

Comment: Edited my out-of-date answer with a different approach to your problem.

Comment: Yes now it is 100%! Thank you